# Currently no loaders are configured to process this file. How can I solve this?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

```
ReactDOM.render(
>   <React.StrictMode>
|     <Provider store={Store}>
|       <App />
```

I tried to configure Babel and Webpack, but I'm facing the above error.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  //   mode: 'none',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg)$/,
        use: ['file-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.jsx', '.js'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'),
    }),
  ],
};
```